# Eclipse (and STS) using wrong JDK to start up

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-tool-suite

I have several versions of Java on my system (OS X El Capitan, version 10.11.6). My current `JAVA_HOME` variable is set to a Java 8 JDK, and the `bin` directory is in my path:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```

Nevertheless, whenever I try to start Eclipse or STS, I get a crash, and inside the `.metadata/.log` file in the workspace it includes the line:

```
java.version=9-ea
```

I can edit the `eclipse.ini` file and add a `-vm` flag to get it to start with the proper JVM, but what mystifies me is where Eclipse is getting the wrong information in the first place. Isn't setting `JAVA_HOME` enough? Where else might it be finding Java?

Comment: I think the native launcher of Eclipse uses /usr/libexec/java_home to determine the current JVM to use and I am not aware of a way to change that command to point to a different VM as a default.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but maybe you can use JAVA_HOME in the eclipse.ini file (via $JAVA_HOME) when setting the -vm argument. Maybe worth a try.

Comment: You're right, my `/usr/libexec/java_home` command is pointing to a Java 9 version. Maybe I can just change that link.

Btw, I wish you had put this as an answer rather than a comment, so I could upvote you :)

Comment: you are right, I added this as an answer... :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think the native launcher of Eclipse uses /usr/libexec/java_home to determine the current JVM to use and I am not aware of a way to change that command to point to a different VM as a default.